# TextWrangler Color Formatting and File Extensions

Tags: textwrangler

Is there anyway to force TextWrangler to make alternate file extensions format like html?
I use Twig and I like to name my templates homePage.twig, login.twig etc...  But, sometimes (I don't know why) the code will not format strings, nodes and what not with alternate colors and I just end up with a big block of dark gray text.  If I put  at the top of the page TextWrangler will format the text, but I can't save the file that way.  AND, the kicker is, this doesn't ALWAYS happen.   Sometimes it will format correctly, sometimes it won't and I can't tell what is triggering it.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it under preferences:

[image]

I input .twig and set Map to: HTML.